# crear input a partir de un select

Tags: javascript, html

Trato de generar un input cuando seleccione una opción en un select, el problema es que no puedo adaptarlo a otros select porque lo que hago es usar un Id, incurriría a una mala práctica si utilizo el mismo id para otros select:

**HTML**

```
<th style="border: 0px;">
<label style="color: #323232;">Tipo de pago</label><br>
<div class="input">
    <input style="height:40px" list="pago" id="tipo_pago" type="text" name="tipo_pago" required data- 
    parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="Tipo de pago" onkeyup="mayus(this);" autocomplete="off" 
    class="form-control option"/>                                                                              
   <datalist id="pago">                                                                                      
       <option id="1" value="1">                                                                                        
       <option value="BONO">
       <option value="CONTADO">                                                                             
   </datalist>
</div>
```

```
<th style="border: 0px;">                                                                                 
  <div id="input"></div>
</th>
```

**JavaScipt**

Encontré este código en internet para poder generar un input cuando selecciono una opción de un select:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var select = document.querySelector(".option");
        var i = "";
        var input = document.querySelector("#input");
        select.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            input.innerHTML = '';
            for (i = 0; i < select.value; i++) {
                createInputs();
            }
        });
        function createInputs() {
            var element = document.createElement('div');
            element.innerHTML = `
                <select style="width: 200px; height:40px" data-parsley-trigger="change" class="form-control" class="mdb-select md-form">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona</option>
                    <option>Mustard</option>
                    <option>Ketchup</option>
                    <option>Relish</option>
                </select>
            `;
            input.appendChild(element);
        }
    });
```

No sé si haya otra forma que no sea la de capturar un id, sino una clase que pueda adaptarla a cualquier select y que no me tome el value=1, porque no puedo añadir el nombre de esa opción

Answer (score 0):

si quieres generar un input al seleccionar un select puedes hacer esto

```
select = document.getElementById('select');
select.addEventListener('click',function(){
    temp = `<input type="text" id="tu_id" value="el_valor">`
});
```

y luego lo puedes poner donde tu quieras con

```
element = document.getElementById('elemento')
element.innerHtml = temp
```

y si quieres capturar por clase tambien lo puedes hacer, y si quieres capturar vaios select por clase y añadir un evento lo haces con un ciclo for

Comment: Ahh ok, pero el problema es que no soy muy bueno en javascript, así que no entiendo muy bien lo que me dijiste. el problema es que tengo qu añadir un value=1 y al dar click este me añade el input, no hay forma de que yo le aplique una clase y no me tome el value =1 para generar un input nuevo?

Comment: el value=1 es el que está en el datalist, por lo tanto no puedo colocar el nombre que es de esa opción. En vez de value=1 tengo que colocar **CRUZAR PAGO**

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas sobre los templates https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/template e investigues sobre los eventos en javascript